# Explanation of the token-based password-reset functionality in Flask-Security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Can someone walk me through what's happening in flask-security's password reset token?  The code is here on github:

https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/recoverable.py

(There may be other parts up a directory.)

My understanding of what's happening:

1. In the route defined by forgot_password() user submits a form to reset password
2. A "reset_password_token" is generated.  This consists of the user's ID + an md5() of the user's current (stored-encrypted) password?
3. A link is generated to a reset password address containing the token.
4. This link is emailed to the address given by user.email
5. When the user clicks that link, they go to a route (defined in views), which is reset_password(token).  The token value is an argument to this route.
6. The route evaluates whether the token is valid and not expired.
7. If so, this route renders a form asking for a new password, ResetPasswordForm().

Is that correct?

Also:

1. If above is correct, is it safe to make the token contain a new md5() of the current password?  I know it should be unique and costly to reverse, but still?
2. Where is the expiration date stored?

I'm most specifically confused by the generate_password_reset function

`data = [str(user.id), md5(user.password)]
    return _security.reset_serializer.dumps(data)`

and the

`get_token_status(token, 'reset', 'RESET_PASSWORD')` function inside `reset_password_token_status(token)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is using the `itsdangerous` module to serialize the token. If you read more about it below, you will have your answers on how expiration timestamp is used etc.

http://packages.python.org/itsdangerous/

The function `serializer.dumps()` creates a unique serialized string and `serializer.loads()` which is called by `get_token_status` will return exceptions unless the exact serialized value is provided to it as parameter.

So you `dumps()` and then using the return value from that, you calls `loads()`. If does not match, you have exception which in this case means bad token.